# Generics - How can i put this code into Generics

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming

How can i put this code into Generic form ?

```
List aviary = new ArrayList();
Eagle any Eagle;
aviary.add(new Eagle(100, "Brutus"));
aviary.add(new Eagle(100, "Chronos"));
for (int i=0; i<aviary.size(); i++) {
anyEagle = (Eagle) aviary.get(i);
anyEagle.hunt();
}
```

Comment: It's all explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: Did you try `List<Eagle>` ? Some IDEs will help you use generics, and even format your code. ;)

Comment: Just fill in <Eagle>?

Comment: BTW Javascript has nothing to do with Java so I'm removing it from the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics and the for-each loop like this in Java 7

```
List<Eagle> aviary = new ArrayList<>();
aviary.add(new Eagle(100, "Brutus"));
aviary.add(new Eagle(100, "Chronos"));

for (Eagle eagle: aviary)
    eagle.hunt();
```

Answer (score 0):

First line needs to be changed to

```
List<Eagle> aviary = new ArrayList<>();
```

I assume Eagle is a valid object that you have.
If you change the line above, you can get rid of the typecasting in this line

```
anyEagle = (Eagle) aviary.get(i);
```